# android cross promotion architecture

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, architecture, ads, surfaceview

I have an architecture question. I have 10 android apps and I want to create a cross promotion system in those apps - which means, every time a user opens one of those apps - they will see an interstitial ad that promotes another app.

In a very basic architecture, all I did was creating an AWS database which contains the URLs of the other apps and the ad in an mp4 format.
Then, when a user opens an app, I have a class that randomly chooses from the AWS db an ad and shows it to the user -> it loads the mp4 video and displays it to the user using android class video `SurfaceView`.

I'm currently facing to major issues:

1. the buffer until the ad loads is very long - unlike other ads I see on other apps that loads a video ad in seconds.
2. the bandwidth that being used from AWS is very high - because every time the user open an app the video is loading.

anyone has suggestions how can I improve my architecture and solve my main two problems?

Comment: Wow, I learnt a new word today: "interstitial" noun COMPUTING, an advertisement that appears while a chosen website or page is downloading.

Answer (score 1):

I'm no expert on videos or AWS, so can't give specific advice on that.

**Some random advice, no specific order:**

Can you preload the ad's onto the devices, so that the app just picks an ad and displays it without having to stream it live?  Your problem then becomes one of getting them onto the devices, but you don't have the same "user impacting" pressures.  I'm assuming you could maybe provide a couple of default videos with the app install, so that first views can be handled while the more up-to-date ads are acquired.

Are the other ads you are comparing to actually mp4?

Have you tried testing using different devices, networks, etc?

Have you tried hosting the video on non-AWS platforms / locations?

Is there a reference architecture or implementation you can refer to to validate your approach?

Have you done the background research into how best to stream/download mp4 content to devices, and play it most efficiently?  E.g. formats, sizes, quality settings, etc - for AWS, the devices your app is on, the tech stack you're using, the player you're using?  I'm thinking here (not related to your issue) about the kind of advice that YouTube gives in terms of video quality for uploading & processing, etc.

Is your SurfaceView set-up to play as soon as it has a buffer ready to go, or is it doing a full download (maybe you have a mis-configuration)?

Comment: thanks, indeed those are good quetsions to start with.